# Substrate Node Error: Denied request: HTTP header: host value verification failed

Tags: polkadot-js, substrate-node-template

I am trying to run a Substrate node with a custom configuration using the following command:

```
  ./target/release/node-template \
  --base-path /tmp/pikamo \
  --chain ./customSpecRaw.json \
  --port 30333 \
  --telemetry-url "wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0" \
  --validator \
  --rpc-methods Unsafe \
  --name PikamoTestNet \
  --ws-external \
  --rpc-external \
  --unsafe-ws-external \
  --unsafe-rpc-external \
  --password-interactive
```

When I try to access the node externally, I encounter the following error:

> Denied request: HTTP header: `host` value: `65.109.4.218:9944` verification failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is cause by the `rpc-cors` rule.

Try `--rpc-cors all`.